# Fetch Records from Mysql By Splicting the value of the column "122-362-25-36"

Tags: mysql

Fetch Records from Mysql By Splicting the value of the column "122-362-25-36":
Remove the (-) sign and search the records in table containing the value
122-362-25-36 => 1223622536
125-365-36-56 => 1253653656 and Search by SQL Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's not clear you exact question but as per i got i think solution
>   should be:-

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (SELECT REPLACE('122-362-25-36','-','') AS ID);
```